# How can I load a scene in unity with a spawn rate variable that increments every time the scene is loaded?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is for a Horde/ Tower defence style game where each level there will be an increased spawn rate to make it slightly more difficult

Comment: Have a singleton that you store the number of loads in

Comment: Absolutely don't use scenes for this.

Comment: Well you can do it with creating some class that has `static` variable.

Comment: Surely, you're only using [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely have to use scenes, then use the the `Object.DontDestroyOnLoad` 
to store the spawn rate over multiple scene loads.

Ref: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html